# Where is the Krux Documentation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, documentation, krux

I am eager to work with Krux and would love to hear from anyone that has pointers to resources on this. Yet where can we find any documentation or tutorials to get started ?

Comment: Did i manage to answer in full, or would you like more detailed information? :)

Comment: No sweat ! :-) Just having a review of old answers, and want to make sure I've served enough detail throughout :) Salesforce DMP (Krux) is currently using a different learning platform - bridgeapp.com i believe. It might migrate to trailhead in the near future (hoping), but we'll see :)

Comment: Brilliant! Also just took a look at their website and it has changed alot since the "rebrand". Worth taking a look at : http://www.krux.com/platform

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Interesting with the new DSaaS area :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there isn't all that much documentation available at all - must of the documentation are provided via LIVE accounts, through webinars to customers etc. If you are connected with the right partner managers, you might be able to get access to the (scarce) online learning that debuted on May 1st i believe.

But, KRUX is in ***very*** hot demand, so the krux ressources can be hard to get your hands on. There isn't a sandbox type environment either - not yet at least.